# Co-integration Regression

Tags: time-series, cointegration

When running a co-integration regression, can I add other variables quantitative and/or dummy control variables in? If so, do they need to be I(0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to avoid is a regression in which there are some I($d$) variables with $d>0$ that do not cointegrate. If this occured, the left hand side of the regression model would diverge from the right hand side, and the model would not make sense. Other than that, you can add quantitative and/or dummy variables.

For cointegrating variables, it may be convenient to use an error-correction model where all the variables as entered in the model are I(0). Thus you would use original I(0) variables if there are any and I(0) transformations and/or combinations of non-I(0) variables such as (i) first differences of I(1) variables and (ii) error correction terms comprised of integrated variables.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful.

Comment: @Boom, you are welcome!